# How do i turn this jquery into javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I can't use Jquery here. please help me change these 3 selector into javascript.
I already tried document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtName').value; but i doesn't work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SetButtonStatus() {
        var tb1 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtName').value;
        var tb2 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtMessage').value;
        var tb3 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtEmail').value;
        if (tb1.length >= 5 && tb2.length >= 5 && tb3.length >= 5)
            makeBtn();
        else
        $('#FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit')[0].control.set_enabled(false);
    }
    function makeBtn() {
        $('#FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit')[0].control.set_enabled(true);
    }
    function ClearValues(sender, args) {
        $('#FeedbackLightBox_txtName').val('');
        $('#FeedbackLightBox_txtMessage').val('');
        $('#FeedbackLightBox_txtEmail').val('');
        args.set_cancel(true);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying `var tb1 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtName').value;` doesn't work, or what? What exactly does not work and why? Which errors do you get? [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. If you have a specific problem/question, ask it. Asking someone to do work for you is not what SO is for.

Comment: if that works then document.getElementById('FeedBack...').control.set_enabled(true) would work, do you get any error messages?

Comment: It looks like you have controls in a form, which are easily accessible as properties of the form so likely the code can be significantly reduced.

Comment: Felix Kling you didn't even read well my question and i did paid freelancer and the freelancer gave me jquery now i can'tmake him take of the jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit').control.set_enabled(false);

document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtName').value = '';
```

**JFYI**

When you say

```
$('#FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit')[0] // it gives you an access to HTML element object which is equivalent to saying `document.getElementById('Feed..)`.
```

Comment: this: $('#FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit')[0].control.set_enabled(false);
isnot equal to this: (it's not working on this sample. document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit').control.set_enabled(false);

Comment: Thank you RobG, RPM and Pilot and everyone who answered. I got it working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, where `.control.set_enabled(false);` is defined on the element, but I guess you do know.

```
function SetButtonStatus() {
        var tb1 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtName').value;
        var tb2 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtMessage').value;
        var tb3 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtEmail').value;
        if (tb1.length >= 5 && tb2.length >= 5 && tb3.length >= 5) {
                makeBtn();
        } else {
            document.getElementById("FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit").control.set_enabled(false);
        }
}
function makeBtn() {
        document.getElementById("FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit").control.set_enabled(true);
}
function ClearValues(sender, args) {
        document.getElementById("FeedbackLightBox_txtName").value = '';
        document.getElementById("FeedbackLightBox_txtMessage").value = '';
        document.getElementById("FeedbackLightBox_txtEmail").value = '';
        args.set_cancel(true);
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a form something like:

```
<form id="FeedbackLightBox_form" onsubmit="return validate(this)" action="">
  Name: <input name="FeedbackLightBox_txtName"><br>
  Message: <teaxtArea name="FeedbackLightBox_txtMessage"></textarea><br>
  Email: <input name="FeedbackLightBox_txtEmail"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit">  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

that you want to check something has been entered into each field before submission, so you validate it using:

```
function validate(form) {
  var control, controls = form.controls;
  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];
    if (control.type != 'submit' && control.value.length < 5) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The *clearForm* function is entlirely unnecessariy if you inlcude a reset button, but anyway:

```
function clearForm() {
  document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_form').reset();
}
```

Similarly, the (inappropriately named) *makeBtn* function can be:

```
function makeBtn() {
    document.betElementById('FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit').disabled = false;
}
```

Maybe it should be called *enableBtn*?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery is only used for getting HTML elements so you could define these as global variables before your functions (or pass them as function arguments) to avoid duplication.

```
var tb1 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtName');
var tb2 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtMessage');
var tb3 = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_txtEmail');
var btn = document.getElementById('FeedbackLightBox_btnSubmit');

function SetButtonStatus() {
    if (tb1.value.length >= 5 && tb2.value.length >= 5 && tb3.value.length >= 5)
        makeBtn();
    else
        btn.control.set_enabled(false);
}
function makeBtn() {
    btn.control.set_enabled(true);
}
function ClearValues(sender, args) {
    tb1.value = '';
    tb2.value = '';
    tb3.value = '';
    args.set_cancel(true);
    return false;
}
```